# How do you combine a number list with multiple outputs give by a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

just a quick note: the title may not be 100% accurate as i dont really know how to explain my problem.

Im creating a Caesar cipher which will repeat all 26 different variations, the problem here is that beside the outputted text i would like to number each variation but it doesnt work.

```
message = """SAHH"""  # Add Code
message = message.upper()
keyShift = 1
encryptedMsg = ""
Waste = '  '



#running the program
while keyShift <= 26:
    for character in message:
        if character.isalpha() == True:
            x = ord(character) - 65
            x += keyShift
            x = x % 26
            encryptedMsg += chr(x + 65)
        else:
            encryptedMsg += character

    for a in enumerate(encryptedMsg, 1):
        print('{}'.format(a),encryptedMsg,"\n")
        encryptedMsg = Waste

        keyShift +=1
```

If you run this the out put will be Each letter of the first variation will have it's own number.

```
for a in enumerate(encryptedMsg, 1):
     print('{}'.format(a),encryptedMsg,"\n")
```

The aim is as i said above each variation of the Caesar cipher should have a number and this code gives a number to each letter of the first variation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you need to create a dictionary of results instead of enumerating your message. I do not quite understand what you are trying to achieve with your later for loop, though.

Do you just want to create all variations of caesar with a different key shift and print them?  If so, this will (probably) do it, assuming your code is correct:

```
message = """SAHH"""  # Add Code
message = message.upper()
keyShift = 1
encryptedMsg = ""
Waste = '  '
results = {}


#running the program
while keyShift <= 26:
    encryptedMsg = ""
    for character in message:
        if character.isalpha() is True:
            x = ord(character) - 65
            x += keyShift
            x %= 26
            encryptedMsg += chr(x + 65)
        else:
            encryptedMsg += character

    results[keyShift] = encryptedMsg
    keyShift =+ 1


for r in results.keys():
    print r, results[r]
```

Or did you mean something else?

Hannu

Comment: Thank You, and yes this is what i meant :D

Comment: Just edited the answer a bit to produce results numbered 1-26 instead of 2-27. Sorry about that.

Comment: Can you just explain to me how your part of the code works as i've not used Dict functions. The last 4 lines of code starting from results[keyshift]

Comment: Also can you tell me why you put encryptedMsg = " " between While loop and for loop and why it does what it does . Thank you

Comment: Dictionaries are a way of indexing a list or array with keywords instead of ordinal numbers. r[4] = "foo" and r["xyzzy"] = "bar" are equally valid statements for the same dictionary r. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries    The reason for having encryptedMsg = "" there is that it needs to be emptied before a new iteration with an increased keyShift can commence. Otherwise your first iteration would produce the correct result and all others would be just appending to that.  Remove it from the code, run it and see the difference. Easier to do that than explain.